# Why I use buildbot tool with p4, the "console view" cannot work?

Tags: perforce, buildbot

This question made me crazy!Please help me.
I use the buildbot, VC tool is perforce 2010.
Waterfall: ok
but console view cannot work right.
just print "No revisions available"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `Periodic` scheduler, then buildbot isn't made aware of the revisions in your repository, it just checks every time, and builds the most recent version. Since it doesn't know anything about revisions, it can't display anything sensible for the console view.

To get the console view, you need to tell buildbot about your revisions, either using [`buildbot.changes.p4poller.P4Source`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/manual/cfg-changesources.html#p4source), [`buildbot send-change`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/manual/cfg-changesources.html#pbchangesource) or [`contrib/post-build-request.py`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/manual/cfg-changesources.html#change-hooks-http-notifications). And then trigger your builds using a [regular scheduler](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#singlebranchscheduler), rather than a periodic one.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably something environmental in the configuration, such as the Perforce username or the Perforce client spec. The tool is probably issuing a 'changes' or 'sync' command, and since it's not using the workspace definition that you expect, it isn't finding any code in that workspace.

Comment: I use this tool by Periodic command.The code can be compile & test.

Comment: Just the console view can not be print.